# Add link type field confused?

Tags: navigation

There is a requirement in my website: The post content should have a link (it is for IOS device to install apps) like the following.

```
<a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=http://www.mywebsitname.com/appdown/CESBGM.plist" class="STYLE17">Install APP</a>
```

I used the Ckeditor and it can make it.

Is there any other ways to make it? I tried the Link module, but it failed.

Answer (score 1):

Drupal has a function called `filter_xss_bad_protocol` that strips unknown protocols from links created with the `l()` function - This is a very smart idea but makes it difficult when you want to include emerging link protocols like `skype://` for example. Dave Reid has created a fantastic module that works around this and allows developers to add their own protocols to the list.

http://drupal.org/project/filter_protocols

With that module installed, and your specific protocol added to its configuration screen, it would then be possible to do something like this in your code:

`<?php print l("Displayed Text", "itms-services://?action=download-manifest"?>`

Additionally, use the `attributes` and `query` parameters of the `l()` function to pass your url parameter to the link. See this for an example... http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/l/7 - You'll find the particular comment regarding passing parameters on that page here: http://api.drupal.org/comment/38198#comment-38198

Hope that helps! Good luck.

P.S. To clarify, simply adding the above module and configuring it will also allow the Link module to respect the protocol since it passes everything through `l()` - So no code required. :) Merely for completeness.

Comment: ,Thank you for your replay. I have been google it for a long time.
I try to use the filter_protocols module,and try to add the itms-services protocol but get the message:Invalid protocol itms-services. The protocol cannot be added. what should i do know now ?

Comment: I have no idea what to do?

Comment: God bless me，to solve it

Comment: Can you please be more specific in how you are adding it? What exactly are you typing into the field?

Comment: my question is to add the itms-services protocol. But ues the filter_protocol cannot add it.the solve the problem follow the instructions in the article:
http://drupal.org/node/185350

I rewrite the settings.php file.

Comment: Solved but no credit? Not nice! :)

Comment: hey @webkenny the itms-services protocol was added, but still have problem,see http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/64459/link-field-and-itms-services-protocol-issue

and I think that  http:// becomes http%3A  resulting in the App installation always failed.

why  this happend

Comment: i see you reply carefully @webkenny, I guess it maybe the l()function .How can i fix it?