# How to add any kind of links and do not to think about it's protocol

Tags: navigation

a itms-services protocol link confused me a lot,I wonder if We can create links that do not have to think about it's protocol

Comment: is it drupal related?

Comment: yes. @monymirza http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/63789/add-link-type-field-confused